# Is there any better way to put jquery json data in html tables

Tags: jquery, html, json

Current i have this code.

1. It gets the json from the url
2. For the first level , i put header column on left and data on right like student info
3. For the other nested data like student.subjects i make the table with header form keys and data from vals

   ```
   $.getJSON('api/data.json', function(data) {
       var student = [];
       $.each(data, function(key, val) {
       student.push('<tr><td>' +key+'</td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
       });



       var subjects = [];
       subject.push('<table><tr>');

       $.each(data.subject[0], function (key, val) {
           decision.push('<th>' +key+'</th>');
       });

       subject.push('</tr><tr>');

       $.each(data.subject, function () {
           mydata = this   
           $.each(mydata, function (key, val) {
                   subject.push('<td>'+val+'</td>');
               });

               subject.push('</tr><tr>');
       });

       subject.push('</tr></table>');


       $(student.join('')).appendTo('table#student_table');
       $(subject.join('')).appendTo('table#subject_table');

   });
   ```

Is there any generic way that it automatically detects like `data.subjects` rather than hard coding so that if there is array fo subjects then it adds the new table rows below that.

This code looks dirty , any better approach for that

Answer (score 0):

I don't like mixing markup and code. I'd recommend using a templating engine for rendering data. Many others are available, but one common templating engine is [jQuery template](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl).

To apply it to your question, you'd do something like this:

```
var studentRow = "<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${val}</td></tr>";

// Compile the markup as a named template
$.template("studentTable", studentRow);

$.getJSON('api/data.json', function(data) {
    $.tmpl("studentTable", data).appendTo("table#student_table");
}
```

But you'd need to alter the markup in `#student_table` to include the beginning and end of the table.

Comment: they say that its not being actively developed

Comment: You can have a go at Mustache.js or underscore.js Your code will be clearer and easier to read (and maintain) with a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself mixing excessive HTML tags in your javascript, you're probably in need of a templating solution. [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) has a `_.template()` function that will solve this for you:

## the javascript

```
$.getJSON('api/data.json', function(data) {
    var compiled_student = _.template($("template-student-row".html(), {data:data}));
    $("#student_table").append(compiled_student);

    var compiled_subject = _.template($("template-subject-row".html(), {keys: Object.keys(data.subject[0]), subjects: data.subject)}));
    $("#subject_table").append(compiled_subject);

});
```

## the html

```
<script id='template-student-row' type='text/template'>
<% _.each(data, function(k,v){ %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= k %></td>
        <td><%= v %></td>
    </tr>
<% }); %>
</script>

<script id='template-subject-row' type='text/template'>
    <tr>
        <% _.each(keys, function(k){ %> <th><%= k %></th> <% }); %>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <% _.each(subjects, function(s){ %> <td><%= s %></td> <% }); %>
    </tr>
</script>

<table id='student_table'></table>
<table id='subject_table'></table>
```